# WPF Prism EventAggregator subscriber does not get the published event

Tags: wpf, events, prism

I am trying to implement Prism EventAggregator in building an App using Prism.
My design is as below:
Publisher VM class

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private LADataService lADataService;
        LADataService sa = new LADataService();
        public List<LAInfo> LADetails
        {
            get
            {
                return this._laDetails;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._laDetails != value)
                {
                    this._laDetails = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("LADetails");
                }
            }
        }

        public  LAInfo SelectedLA
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedla;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedla != value)
                {
                    _selectedla = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedLA");
                    //NavigationParameters navParameter = new NavigationParameters();

                    //navParameter.Add("SelectedLA", SelectedLA);
                    
                    // Publish event.
                    iEventAggregator
                        .GetEvent<PubSubEvent<LAInfo>>()
                        .Publish(this.SelectedLA);
                }
            }
        }
```

Subscriber VM

```
class PopUpFormViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INavigationAware
    {
        private LAInfo _lainfo;
        public LAInfo LAInfo
        {

            get
            {
                return this._lainfo;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._lainfo != value)
                {
                    this._lainfo = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("LAInfo");
                }
            }

        }
  public PopUpFormViewModel(IEventAggregator iEventAggregator)
        {
            this.iEventAggregator = iEventAggregator;
            this
                .iEventAggregator
                .GetEvent<PubSubEvent<LAInfo>>()
                .Subscribe((details) =>
                {
                    this.LAInfo = details;
                });
        }
```

Publisher xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="USBReaderFinal.Views.Main"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:USBReaderFinal.Views"
             xmlns:design="clr-namespace:USBReaderFinal.Designer"
             
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="71*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="154*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="108*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="287*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="31*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="63*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="351*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>-->

            <materialDesign:Card
  materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth3"
  materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowEdges="Bottom"
  Padding="32"
  Content="LAs with Max Date.Right click the list content to Select/Add/View graphs" FontSize="16" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" OpacityMask="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InfoBrushKey}}" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                <materialDesign:Card.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF00FF91" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </materialDesign:Card.Background>
            </materialDesign:Card>
            <Frame
               x:Name="NavigationFrame"
               NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
               
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
               ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
               ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
               Margin="6" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               />
            <ListView Name="LA" ItemsSource="{Binding LADetails}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLA}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="215" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="649" Margin="94,36,0,0" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >

                <ListView.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Name="Add" Header="Add New LA"  />
                        <MenuItem Name="Update" Header="Update LA"  />
                        <MenuItem Name="Delete" Header="Delete Selected LA"  />
                        <MenuItem Name="Graph" Header="Display Graph"  />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListView.ContextMenu>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <WrapPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="LAName: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LAname}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text=", " />
                            <TextBlock Text=" LAMAke: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LAMAke}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" Phase:  " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phase}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" Board:  " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Board}" FontWeight="Bold" />

                            <TextBlock Text=" FF:  " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ld.FF}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" CTHD:  " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ld.Cthd}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" TTHD:  " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ld.TThd}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" Temp:  " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ld.Temp}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" Comptemll:  " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ld.Comptell}" FontWeight="Bold" />

                            <TextBlock Text=" Date:  " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ld.Max_date}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </WrapPanel>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Subscriber xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="USBReaderFinal.Views.PopUpFormUSB"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" 
               
             xmlns:design="clr-namespace:USBReaderFinal.Designer"
           
             mc:Ignorable="d"  
             d:DesignHeight="450" Width="800">
    <Grid >
       
        <StackPanel Margin="108,0,0,0">
            <Label Content="LAName" Width="71"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="DarkOrange" FontSize="14"/>
            <Label Content="LAMake" Width="71"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="DarkOrange" FontSize="14"/>
            <Label Content="CTHD" Width="71"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="DarkOrange" FontSize="14"/>
            <Label Content="FF" Width="113"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="DarkOrange" FontSize="14"/>
            <Label Content="Temp" Width="113"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="DarkOrange" FontSize="14"/>

        </StackPanel>
       
        <StackPanel Margin="345,0,0,0">
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding LAInfo}">
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
         
            </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentControl>
            <TextBox Width="201"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="AliceBlue" Height="30" 
                     Text="{Binding LAName,
                                Delay=1000,
                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     OpacityMask="#FF00A2FF" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" />

            <TextBox Width="201"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="AliceBlue" Height="30"
                     Text="{Binding LAMake,
                                Delay=1000,
                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" />
            <TextBox Width="201"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="AliceBlue" Height="25" Text="{Binding CTHD,
                                Delay=1000,
                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}"/>
            <TextBox Width="201"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="AliceBlue" Height="23" Text="{Binding FF,
                                Delay=1000,
                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}"/>
            <TextBox Width="201"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="27" Text="{Binding Temp, Delay=1000, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Basically when I select an item from the listview of main, the selected item
should pass as an paramter to Popup view.

When I debugged the eventaggregator code, in the Subscriber VM I get null passed for the
LAInfo object in below code

public PopUpFormViewModel(IEventAggregator iEventAggregator)
{
this.iEventAggregator = iEventAggregator;
this
.iEventAggregator
.GetEvent<PubSubEvent>()
.Subscribe((details) =>
{
this.LAInfo = details;
});
}

Bootstrapper (In case required)

```
class BootStrapper : AutofacBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureContainerBuilder(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.ConfigureContainerBuilder(builder);


            
            //builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().SingleInstance();
            //  builder.RegisterType<DataPassOnService>().As<ILAInfos>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<LADataService>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<USBDataService>().SingleInstance();
            //builder.RegisterType<DataPassOnService>().SingleInstance();
    
            builder.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Main>("Main");
            builder.RegisterTypeForNavigation<LeftMenu>("LeftMenu");
            builder.RegisterTypeForNavigation<PopUpFormUSB>("PopUpFormUSB");
            builder.RegisterTypeForNavigation<USBListAccess>("USBListAccess");

            //           builder.RegisterType<USBListAccessViewModel>()
            // //.As<IUSBService>()
            // .UsingConstructor(typeof(USBDataService));

            //           builder.RegisterType<PopUpFormViewModel>().InstancePerRequest();
            ////.As<ILAInfos>()
            //.UsingConstructor(typeof(DataPassOnService));
        }
```

What is happening here and why I am seeing null here, this is the object which I am planning to
pass to the Subscriber xaml, which will not reach as the code will exception out due to null pointer exception.
Do I need to pass on the above selected item to NavigateTo method which will navigate to the second view with the selected parameter? If so, how do I go about doing it? I am kind of stuck. Any sort of direction is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the null reference exception happen and why didn't you fix that?

Comment: public PopUpFormViewModel(IEventAggregator iEventAggregator)
        {
            this.iEventAggregator = iEventAggregator;
            this
                .iEventAggregator
                .GetEvent<PubSubEvent<LAInfo>>()
                .Subscribe((details) =>
                {
                    this.LAInfo = details; // LAInfo is null, which should recieve the data published from the publisher, since it does not get the subscribed data from publisher, hence it is null, not sure how to fix this as I believe evenaggregation does not work
                });
        }

Comment: This seems unlikely - `LAInfo = details;` won't throw a null reference exception if `LAInfo` is null before the assignment.